# MongoDB Replication Set Configuration Issue on CentOS 7

Tags: replication, mongodb, centos-7

My mongodb instance will not run as standalone and I haven't been able to discover why.  Its probably something simple.  Please point me in the right direction.

```
Linux myserver 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 mongo -version
MongoDB shell version v4.0.6
```

running the command:

> > mongo --host 10.0.0.7/admin --port 27017 -u user -p mypassword

returns:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.13
connecting to: mongodb://admin:27017/?replicaSet=10.0.0.7
2019-03-06T00:54:32.412-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] Starting new replica set monitor for 10.0.0.7/admin:27017
2019-03-06T00:54:32.414-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] getaddrinfo("admin") failed: Name or service not known
2019-03-06T00:54:32.414-0500 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set 10.0.0.7
2019-03-06T00:54:32.414-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] All nodes for set 10.0.0.7 are down. This has happened for 1 checks in a row.
2019-03-06T00:54:32.914-0500 I NETWORK  [thread1] getaddrinfo("admin") failed: Name or service not known
```

So I logged into mongo shell on the host and ran:

`use admin
 show users`

```
{
        "_id" : "admin.myname",
        "user" : "myname",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
                "SCRAM-SHA-1",
                "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ] }
```

and

> rs.status()

```
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "not running with --replSet",
        "code" : 76,
        "codeName" : "NoReplicationEnabled"
}
```

Mongd.conf

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
#  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  dbPath: /data/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.
  bindIpAll: true

security:
  authorization: "enabled"

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mongo --host 10.0.0.7/admin --port 27017 -u user -p mypassword

The above command takes `10.0.0.7` as `replica set` name and `admin` as the `hostname`. That is the reason you are getting the error.

Use any of the following commands to connect to your MongoDB database

```
mongo 10.0.0.7/admin --port 27017 -u user -p mypassword

mongo admin --host 10.0.0.7 --port 27017 -u user -p mypassword
```